# How to import a Python module into Jython?

Tags: python, import, jython, importerror

I can use the module correctly by Python, but when using Jython, some error occurs...
Code:

```
from jieba import *
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jack/Documents/workspace/FirstJython/hellojyphon.py", line 8, in <module>
    from jieba import *
  File "/Users/Jack/Documents/workspace/FirstJython/jieba/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ._compat import *
ImportError: No module named _compat
```

Is there any differences between Python and Jython when import?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by myself. 
There is something wrong when using relative directories in Jython. 
so after I change ._compat to jieba._compat, the problem solved!
But I don't exactly know the reason...